# Click Functionality Not Working in QGIS Selection Tools

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

Yesterday, I was using the "select entities by area or single click" tool to select a group of polygons from a shapefile and then using the "change properties of a group of files" tool. Suddenly, the tool stopped working with a single click. It still works when I create a rectangle by holding down the mouse button, but clicking no longer selects anything.

I created a new QGIS file, re-imported all the necessary shapefiles, and restarted my work, but after an hour, the tool stopped working when I clicked (but still works when I create a selection polygon, once again)

I tried closing and reopening QGIS, I tried restarting my computer. I updated my QGIS version from 3.26.2 to 3.34.3. None of these steps were successful.

Comment: Are you able to share a screen recording of the behaviour you are experiencing? Using a software like [Screen To Gif](https://www.screentogif.com/). The only thing I can think of is that your polygons are styled with a geometry generator or other symbol that extends beyond the actual geometry of the feature. The selection tool will only work on the actual geometry of the feature,. For example in this image I have a thick hatched buffer/outline outside the actual feature geometry. Selecting the hatched part doesn't work, only selecting the geometry does. https://i.imgur.com/zskTUDH.gif